# How to display nested array elements using NgFor in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects,

```
movies = [
    {
    "_id": "61581aa12bee6cbe7b453d1d",
    "movie_title": "Master",
    "genres_list": [
    "Drama"
    ]
    },
    {
    "_id": "615c7f5fbc3bf7d026ee7f7e",
    "movie_title": "Sarpatta Parambarai",
    "genres_list": [
    "Drama",
    "Action",
    "Sports"
    ]
    },
    {
    "_id": "616d57c5653c0a4a55d9cb33",
    "movie_title": "OK Kanmani",
    "genres_list": [
    "Romance",
    "Drama",
    "Feel Good"
    ]
    }]
```

I want to display all the genres_list .

My code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
<span>{{movie.movie_title}}</span>
<div *ngFor = "let genre of movie.genres_list; let i=index">
<h2>{{genre[i]}}</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to display all the genres_list values. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `<h2>{{genre}}</h2>` in your html. Doing `{{genre[i]}}` is essentially treating the genre string as a character array and only prints out a single character of the string at index i.